# How to get updated state in react

Tags: reactjs

I want updated playerNames, so that I cant send it to reducer, but after setting state I am not getting the updated state, both in if and else condition

```
 const [playerNames, setPlayersName] = React.useState([]);

      let updatePlayers = playerNames.map(item=>item.id == event.target.value.id
        ? {...item}
        :item
        
        setPlayersName(updatePlayers)

    }else{
      setPlayersName(prev=>[...prev,event.target.value])
    }

    dispatch(selectPlayers(playerNames))
```

Comment: looks like you're missing some code

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you can dispatch the data without setting the state. Just use event.target.value or a simple let variable = ..., and dispatch that instead. We use states to re-render components, there is no need to set the state if you are going to dispatch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really call the dispatch right after calling the `selectPlayers` hook.

**Why**
In class based component, The `setState` has a callback function that can be executed right after the state update. But in terms of hook we do not have that. But we can achieve that with some tricks.

In your case I would something like this.

**Solution**
At first I would define an `useEffect` and give the `playerNames` as a dependency So whenever the state gets changed it will call dispatch

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(selectPlayers(playerNames))
}, [playerNames])
```

**Why this `useEffect`**
It will give your more power to conditionally call the dispatch and execute it. We can also do it in many other ways like bellow.

```
dispatch(selectPlayers(updatePlayers))
```

Doc link - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous